# Gerrit admininitrator does not access “All-Projects”

Tags: permissions, gerrit

All members in the Administrators group can NOT access "All-Project".

I am afraid that the read permission is removed from "All-Project" for admin.
How can I recover it.
And I can find project.config in the ./All-Project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can still ssh then you can checkout All-Projects.git and edit the config.

If you have access to server, you can even navigate to the All-Project.git directory (its a base repo) and rollback to an earlier change. (Obviously backup everything first if you're not very confident of what you're doing).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I can access to server and get the project.config under the help of http://blog.bruin.sg/2013/04/how-to-edit-the-project-config-for-all-projects-in-gerrit/   I modified the project.config, but still can NOT access All-Projects via web UI. I How to rollback to an earlier change?

Comment: If you can push changes to project.config then you can roll back changes using git too. Instead of rolling back, you can alternatively grant yourself access by editing and pushing changes to project.config, e.g. ```[access "refs/*"] <newline>read = group Administrators```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I roll back (git reset) changes of All-Projects repo and get Administrators Group back. Before that, I tried to modify the project.config, it worked for other project repo but not for All-Projects. Thank you again. That helps a lot.

Comment: What is the right way to roll back to an earlier change of the All-Project.git in the server?   Are the followings right? git reset --hard <commit_id>;  git push origin HEAD --force

Comment: I have found the way to roll back the earlier change of the All-Project.git in the server. Push the corrected files to "refs/meta/config" is useful.